# $bin/hadoop namenode --format error

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop-partitioning

I got this error when I'm trying to execute the this command: `$bin/hadoop namenode –format`

```
/home/MAHI/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 31: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/home/MAHI/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 58: syntax error: unexpected end of file**
# The java implementation to use.  Required.
export JAVA_HOME= "C:\Java\"

# Extra Java CLASSPATH elements.  Optional.
# export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=

# The maximum amount of heap to use, in MB. Default is 1000.
# export HADOOP_HEAPSIZE=2000

# Extra Java runtime options.  Empty by default.
# export HADOOP_OPTS=-server

# Command specific options appended to HADOOP_OPTS when specified
export HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote $HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS"
export HADOOP_SECONDARYNAMENODE_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote $HADOOP_SECONDARYNAMENODE_OPTS"
export HADOOP_DATANODE_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote $HADOOP_DATANODE_OPTS"
export HADOOP_BALANCER_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote $HADOOP_BALANCER_OPTS"
export HADOOP_JOBTRACKER_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote $HADOOP_JOBTRACKER_OPTS"
 export HADOOP_TASKTRACKER_OPTS=
 The following applies to multiple commands (fs, dfs, fsck, distcp etc)
export HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS

 Extra ssh options.  Empty by default.
 export HADOOP_SSH_OPTS="-o ConnectTimeout=1 -o SendEnv=HADOOP_CONF_DIR"

 Where log files are stored.  $HADOOP_HOME/logs by default.
 export HADOOP_LOG_DIR=${HADOOP_HOME}/logs

 File naming remote slave hosts.  $HADOOP_HOME/conf/slaves by default.
 export HADOOP_SLAVES=${HADOOP_HOME}/conf/slaves

 host:path where hadoop code should be rsync'd from.  Unset by default.
 export HADOOP_MASTER=master:/home/$USER/src/hadoop

 Seconds to sleep between slave commands.  Unset by default.  This
 can be useful in large clusters, where, e.g., slave rsyncs can
 otherwise arrive faster than the master can service them.
 export HADOOP_SLAVE_SLEEP=0.1
```

The directory where pid files are stored. `/tmp` by default.
    NOTE: this should be set to a directory that can only be written to by 
    the users that are going to run the hadoop daemons.  Otherwise there is
    the potential for a symlink attack.

```
 export HADOOP_PID_DIR=/var/hadoop/pids

 A string representing this instance of hadoop. $USER by default.
 export HADOOP_IDENT_STRING=$USER

 The scheduling priority for daemon processes.  See 'man nice'.
export HADOOP_NICENESS=10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set JAVA_HOME incorrectly in hadoop-env.sh. Give absolute path of java_home.You can find out java current java path using below command :

```
alternatives --config java
```

It will give all the java version you have installed and pick proper version and set this java path into hadoop-env.sh like below :

```
 export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.*/bin
```

Another approach is to set $JAVA_HOME into user's .bashrc . So no need to required to set into hadoop-env.sh.

Answer (score 0):

> export JAVA_HOME= "C:\Java\"

This shows you are using hadoop in windows environment. But:

> export HADOOP_PID_DIR=**/var/hadoop/pids**

This line shows you are providing folder location as in linux environment.

Don't get confused with windows and linux configurations. **Correct the path to reflect your Operating System**.

Answer (score 0):

Install java in the machine and set the JAVA_HOME path on .bash_profile. Once you do this export the $JAVA_HOME variable so that other processes which are looking for JAVA_HOME can use this path. Also set the JAVA_HOME path in /etc/hadoop/conf/hadoop-env.sh file. 
Note:- Some people install more than one hadoop version. Make sure you are making changes in the correct hadoop system. To see which hadoop system you are currently using perform cat on /etc/alternatives file which will give all the symlinks and make necessary changes.